# Java printf issue with integer indexes of float matrix

Tags: java, matrix, integer, printf, output

I have to print a formatted double matrix in java, with in the first column the number of the line. I'm using this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%d", i);
    for (int j = 0; j < 80; j++) {
        System.out.printf("%5f", P[i][j]);
        System.out.print("  ");
        }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Part of the output is:

[image: output matrix]

The float part is nice, but I don't understand why it add a zero to the integers (in fact multiplicating by ten???) and other decimal zeroes. How can i solve this?

Comment: What is P[i][j]?

Comment: a matrix of double

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not multiplying the integers by ten. It just seems that way because there is no space between the line number and the first double value.

Just add another call to

```
System.out.print("  ");
```

after this line:

```
System.out.printf("%d", i);
```

Then you should see the line numbers seperated from the matrix.

Comment: Strange behavior from java though

Answer (score 0):

The decimal separator unfortunately is implemented as a char and with decimals always present. I have made it an underscore for demonstration. A space might be usable.

When the number has an integer part like 1.2 you seem to want to remove that part; did that.

```
    DecimalFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat(".00000");
    numberFormat.setMaximumIntegerDigits(0);
    numberFormat.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(true); // Not sometimes gone.
    DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = numberFormat.getDecimalFormatSymbols();
    symbols.setDecimalSeparator('_');
    numberFormat.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%d", i); // No space after!
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            System.out.print(numberFormat.format(0.4 * i));
            //System.out.printf("%5f", 0.4 * i);
            System.out.print("  ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```